# The Elder Scroll Skyrim V install on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation, steam

I want to install the Elder Scrolls Skyrim V and I use ubuntu 18.04 and steam but I don't know-how to install and setup on my desktop. How can I install and setup Skyrim on my Ubuntu Desktop 18.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of Steam games just have to:

1. go into `Steam->Settings->Steam Play` and activate Steam Play for every game.
2. Restart Steam
3. Install game using Steam (install button should be now active).

But there is a bit more universal way of playing games on linux.

You can also try [Lutris](https://lutris.net/) .
It is game manager (something like GOG Galaxy 2.0), it allows you to easily install almost every game without need of wine/proton configuration. It is recommended in case of any problem with regular Steam way.

Comment: thanks but it works